# Click event triggering on children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code

```
    <div id="id0_0" class="clearfix" style="margin-left:40px">
       <div id="id0_1" class="choice">
          <span id="spanradio_1" class="radio"> </span>
          <span id="spanlabel_1" class="label"><label id="label_1">Indoor</label></span>
       </div>

       <div id="id0_2" class="choice">
          <span id="spanradio_2" class="radio"> </span>
          <span id="spanlabel_2" class="label"><label id="label_2">Outdoor</label></span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

with the following jQuery:

```
    jQuery('.choice').click( function(e) {
       alert('clicked!! ' + e.target.id);
       var src_ele = $(e.target);

       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;
    });
```

However, my click is triggering on the spanradio's & label's and not the div's. Any reason what is causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pvk7W/

Comment: if you click on the indoor/outdoor text, it doesn't show that it clicked on the divs

Comment: Gah you are right, it is this. I am retarded...

Comment: how to mark a comment as the answer? even though I'm sure no one else will run into this issue, considering how dumb it is :(

Comment: You cannot mark a comment as the accepted answer but it looks like @pimvdb has also supplied an answer that is what you are looking for. If it is correct, you should accept it. I wouldn't worry if you think this is a question that will not help others. Quite the opposite I think as it has a good title, example code that describes the problem and an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically:

- `this` is the element you bound the event to (i.e. one of the elements in the set that you called `.on` on)
- `e.target` is the deepest element you clicked on

So you want `this.id`.

Answer (score 1):

`e.target` is the element that the user actually clicked on.

If the user clicked on a nested element, `e.target` will be that element.

Comment: but shouldn't jQuery('.choice') filter click triggering only to those with choice class??

Comment: @user1181950: Yes, but you still get a click event if you click the child element.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I was hoping to filter all click events within .choice (and its children) and only trigger on the .choice level. Is that possible? So in essence e.target will always be the div and not the child label/span's even though the actual click is on the child...

Comment: As pimvdb mentioned... I just need to use this... I am retarded, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

because the label is the ONLY content in a ".choice"-element and therefore is on the TOP --> it's actually the element, you clicked on...

check out `event.relatedTarget` if this is the right one for you.